# Image Retrieving

Tags: windows-phone-7

Im doing App with Camera in Windows Phone. Can Any one say that How can I get Image After Clicking with Camera Capture I want to Display that Image in Other Page and I like to add Some  Mater About that and than I like to Save. please any One Guide Me

Comment: Take a look on http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/02/28/windows-phone-7-working-with-camera-tasks/ Most interesting part for you is 'Displaying the selected photograph'